# Where should I put my css file in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, html, css, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am writing a very simple web application project by "*IntelliJ IDEA*" and "*Tomcat*". I downloaded and HTML file and pasted it into my index.jsp, this HTML also has a css file, but I do not know where to put it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put css anywhere in project . All you need to select correct path in href .

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path_to_css/xyz.css">
</head>
```

you can put css and html in same directory. then use

```
 <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="xyz.css">
</head>
```